# How can I watch [java*] tags without [javascript*]?

Tags: support, tags, search, tag-watching

I realized that my [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag wasn't catching [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8), so I changed it to [java*] (like I saw somewhere here on Meta).

Then I realized that I was getting [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) in my results too. I don't want to ignore JS, but I can't have it coming up when I click [java*] in my tag list. How can I watch [java*] without getting [javascript*] results too?

---

Not that this prevents anyone from tagging JavaScript questions with Java. That's a different issue.

Comment: I think `[java] or [java-*]` could do the job.

Comment: @Floern no, both would miss javafx

Comment: Think like a programmer.  Add [javascript] to your Ignored Tags section.

Comment: @HansPassant Did you read what I wrote? I specifically said `I don't want to ignore JS`. Ignoring tags is not the opposite of favorite tags, because they are removed in most, if not all searches.( Just because I don't know a language doesn't mean I can't write a good answer for an easy question in that language.)

Comment: I ignored that.

Comment: Perhaps this should also be tagged _feature-request_?

Comment: @Tim I thought it might already be a feature.

Comment: How a stupid management/marketing naming decision in 1995 makes lives more complicated for thousands even decades later...

Comment: Better alternative: just squash java-\d tags into java. It will solve many problems.

Answer (score 23):

Since you tagged this as [search](/questions/tagged/search), here's a search that will do what you want:

> [`[java*] -[javascript*] is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava*%5D+-%5Bjavascript*%5D+is%3Aq)

This takes anything tagged as `java*`, then removes anything tagged with any form of `javascript*`. The `is:q` serves to force use of the search system; this overloads the normal tag system.

This probably won't work as a *favorite* tag, it will likely only work as a search.

Comment: Yes, I meant `favorite tags`. But your query should work for regular searches. (Note: I know both of these tricks, and `-[javascript*]` couldn't be conjoined into my single `[java*]` tag)