# Should version-specific tags be used for the latest version?

Tags: discussion, tags, language-versions

Should a question about Java streams include the [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) tag, or should the latest version be assumed by default? At what point does a new version become the assumed standard, making the version-specific tag superfluous?

Comment: My suggestion: Use the version specific tag if the version matters. If your question must use a thing that only exists in your version or can't use a common solution because it's deprecated in your version, then use the the version specific tag.

Comment: @BSMP Generics were introduced in Java 5, but no one uses the `java-5` tag for questions involving generics. Streams were introduced in Java 8, and it's very common to see the `java-8` tag on questions relating to streams.

Comment: I have a beef about this things because their temporal relevance (who says that a question is really "version specific"? Can they know the future?), so I say that only when you are absolutely sure your question will ever be relevant to that version, that will not be ever be relevant to any other version. BTW, I answer those kind of questions by stating all the possible answers if there are changes between versions, like this one http://askubuntu.com/a/420979/169736

Comment: @Braiam, I don't think version tags are exclusive by definition. For example, I might use the `java-6` tag for a question that applies to any version prior to Java 7. Conversely, I might use the `java-9` tag for a new feature that will likely be retained in Java 10.

Comment: And what would be the purpose of that? That the answerer is aware that you are using that version? That can be easily archived by adding that to the body of your question, in case anyone wonders. Remember, [\[T\]ags are a means of **connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer** by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Who in their right mind will think that asking a new question about ["How to allow cyclic dependencies in Java?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35688995/) each time a new version of Java comes out?

Comment: *Generics were introduced in Java 5, but no one uses the java-5 tag for questions involving generics.* Right, because that's not the only version it exists in.

Comment: Or putting it more bluntly: you suddenly forget every knowledge about how to get things done in Java each time a version comes out? I expect that you will answer "no", but who knows?

Comment: @BSMP *because that's not the only version it exists in.* Are you suggesting that the new version tag should be used until the next version is released?

Comment: @Braiam, I'm obviously talking about questions relating to new features introduced in a particular version. Which is why I mentioned Streams in my post.

Comment: And I told you: will Generics disappear in the next version of Java? Think about the children! Will be relevant to them which version of Java introduced Generics? Is even relevant *now*?

Comment: @Braiam, so if I had a question today about a Java 9 feature, you don't think it would warrant the `java-9` tag? I can accept that opinion; I just want to be clear on your position.

Comment: Because is not a java-9 *only* feature. It will be still relevant for all the java questions to come, or so I hope. But, what if I wanted to make a polyfill for previous versions? Why would an expert of Java not follow the trends and be learned the newest and shinny, yet didn't followed the new tag, because all java questions would be tagged java anyways? What is the great advantage the *extra* tag brings about?

Answer (score 2):

While I can't comment on other languages, this is *Java*. We all know that Java isn't going to be removing features; they like to ensure backwards compatibility.

I would just use the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, unless you are talking about an older version, or the differences between two versions. I get annoyed with java questions that are tagged [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) because I only follow the Java tag (for reasons mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319928/6083675)).

In your case, you are talking about something that didn't exist in Java 7 and earlier, so there's no reason to expect that anyone will come looking for a solution in an earlier version of Java. On the other hand, if someone provides a solution for an earlier version, you can still use it in the current version.

I highly doubt that you're going to remove the tag when the next version comes out, so just use the generic Java tag.

Comment: I'm not suggesting using *only* the `java-8` tag. I'm saying it could be helpful to *include* it when discussing new features, at least until the version has wider adoption.